What is a mathematically rigorous definition of a random sample?
In reading the intermediate-level statistics book by Hogg, McKean and Craig, there is the following discussion of a random sample:
...our information about the unknown distribution of X or the unknown parameters of the distribution of X comes from a sample on X. The sample observations have the same distribution as X, and we denote them as the random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, ..., $X_n$, where $n$ denotes the sample size. When the sample is actually drawn, we use lower case letters $x_1$, $x_2$,..., $x_n$, as the values or realizations of the sample. Often we assume that the sample observations $X_1$, $X_2$, ..., $X_n$ are also mutually independent, in which case we call the sample a random sample, which we now formally define:
Definition 4.1.1. If the random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, ..., $X_n$ are independent and identically distributed (iid), then these random variables constitute a random sample of size n from the common distribution

To this definition, I would like to make 2 comments:

There seems to be some disagreement between the first paragraph and the definition that follows it. In the first paragraph, the sample is said to be drawn on X. But in the definition, the sample is drawn from the common distribution. Because X is a random variable and not a distribution, these two statements are not exactly the same.

In the first paragraph, it is stated that $X_1$, $X_2$, ..., $X_n$ have the same distribution as $X$. This got me thinking: Do $X_1$, $X_2$, ..., $X_n$ have the same domain as $X$? Does an individual $X_i$ have the same domain as some $X_j$, for $i \neq j$?


After thinking about these questions, my initial idea was to try to define each $X_i$ as basically a restriction of $X$. More specifically, I initially proceeded as follows:

If $X: S \to \mathbb{R}$, and $X(s_1), X(s_2), ..., X(s_n)$ are the $n$ observations in the sample, then perhaps I could define $X_i$ by $X_i: \{s_i\} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $X_i(s_i) = X(s_i)$.
By defining each $X_i$ as above, there would be $(n+1)$ probability spaces: $(S, \mathcal{F}, P)$, $(\{s_1\}, \mathcal{F}_1, P_1), ..., (\{s_n\}, \mathcal{F}_n, P_n)$), and $(n+1)$ CDF functions: $F$, $F_1$, ..., $F_n$.
But then I realized that this setup is destined to fail, because $F_1(x) = P_1(X_1 \leq x)$ can only take the values of either 0 or 1, because the probability measure $P_1$ can only take the values 0 or 1, owing to the fact that the $\sigma$-field $F_1$ only has 2 elements, i.e. $F_1 = \{\varnothing, \{s_1\}\}$.

Since $F$ will (almost certainly) not take only 2 values, it would be impossible for $F_1$ and $F$ to be the same function, i.e. it would be impossible for $X$ and $X_1$ to have the same distribution, which is a property that $X$ and $X_1$ should have.
So after my failed attempt at defining $X_1$, $X_2$, ..., $X_n$, I thought it best to ask the community for help. My main question is:
If $X: S \to \mathbb{R}$, what are the domains of $X_1$, $X_2$, ..., $X_n$?
Thank you very much for your help.

Suppose that you have the data ${x_1, \ldots, x_n}$. This data is a bunch of numbers, but you assume that each of these numbers is a particular realization of the random variables $X_1,\ldots, X_n$. Hence,  ${x_1, \ldots, x_n}=  {X_1(w), \ldots, X_n(w)}, $where $w$ is a particular outcome of the random experiment that produced this data, formally speaking, it's just a $w \in \Omega$, where $\Omega$ is any set. Do you have any questions to that I wrote?

@perepelart Thank you for your response. Just to give something more concrete for me to wrap my mind around, suppose that S={all adults in USA}, and $X:S \to R$ is defined by $X(s)$ = # of times $s$ has visited StackExchange in their life. Now suppose we observe the values $X(Sam)$, $X(Mary)$ and $X(Bob)$. So one could say there are 3 RVs in the sample: $X_{Sam}$, $X_{Mary}$ and $X_{Bob}$. How do we compute $X_{Sam}(Mary)$?

When talking about any random variable $X$, the most interesting thing for you is its probability distribution $\mathbb{P}X(\cdot)$. So considering your example, we have the discrete random variables $X_1, X_2, X_3$ and we have $3$ users : ${1,2,3}$, also we know that $\operatorname{ran}(X_1) = \mathbb{N}{0}$. We could describe their probability distributions by their PMFs, $p_{X_1}(\cdot), p_{X_2}(\cdot), p_{X_3}(\cdot)$. As we know, these random variables are identically distributed, then for all $i \in {1, 2, 3}$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}0$ $p{X_i}(n) = p_{X_j}(n).$

Now, we observe three values, ${X_1(1), X_2(2), X_3(3) }$. You cannot answer what is $X_1(2)$ with certainty, you only know that $p_{X_1}(2) =  p_{X_2}(2)$. In practice, the main thing you need is to estimate these probabilities using the data you observed.

@perepelart Thank you for taking the time to reply. I am not sure I completely agree with your sentence "You cannot answer what is $X_1(2)$ with certainty." The RV $X_1$ is a function, and functions are deterministic, in the sense that once we know the input value, the output value is known with 100% certainty.

Suppose $\Omega={100,200}$ and $X \sim \operatorname{Bern}(p)$. What is $X(100)?$

But Bernoulli random variable, by definition, takes only two values - $0$ and $1$. How $X(100) =100$? Note that I could ask this question for any set of the form ${w_1, w_2}$.

@perepelart You are correct that the Bernoulli RV only takes the values 0 and 1. Thank you for emphasizing this, and for correcting me! It is a good learning experience for me :) And so I have deleted my previous comment, and re-written it below with your corrections incorporated.

@perepelart As you have pointed out, the Bernoulli RV only takes the values $0$ and $1$. So $X(100) = 0$ or $X(100) = 1$. The exact definition is specified by the statistician working on the problem. But once this definition of $X$ is written down, then I do not believe there is any randomness in terms of what $X(100)$ gets mapped to, i.e. $X(100)$ will always get mapped to the same thing, from now until the end of time.

Yes, you are right. It depends on our interpretation and both interpretations are mathematically correct. Now, suppose that $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ and $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. What is $X(1)?$

@perepelart I could be wrong, but I don't think I can answer the question: what is $X(1)$? In order to know that, I would need to be told the definition of the function $X$. However, I can answer the question: What is $P(X = 1)$? The answer to that is $0$. And I can also answer the question: What is $P(X \leq 0)$? That is $\Phi(0)$. But I don't think I can answer the question: Where does the element $1$ get mapped to by $X$?

But as you said, $X$ is just a (measurable) function. It's certainly sends $1$ to deterministic value on real line, but you don't know to which one. So my main point is "The concept of random variables as a way to abstract away from the sample space $\Omega$ and focus on probability distributions". That's why you often don't want to talk explicitly about things such as "What is $X_1(2)$?" Sometimes the answer to this question will be "depends on", sometimes it will be just too hard to tell. But in every situation, from the probabilistic perspective, such questions are "superfluous".

@perepelar Thank you. I will think about your comment.

Probability is a mathematical discipline with aims akin to those, for example, of geometry or analytical mechanics. In each field we must carefully distinguish three aspects of the theory: (a) the formal logical content, (b) the intuitive background, (c) the applications. The character, and the charm, of the whole structure cannot be appreciated without considering all three aspects in their proper relation. - Feller

Imagine your random random variable is a spinner. To obtain n samples, you spin the wheel n times and write down the numbers you get. There isnt more to it than that and the formalism isn't important (see above Feller quote)

To really answer this question properly requires a discussion of the question of when two random variables are the same. Importantly, this does not mean that the two random variables are the same function on the same sample space. The sample space is auxiliary and ultimately doesn't really matter. As explained by Terence Tao in 254A, Notes 0: A review of probability theory:

At a purely formal level, one could call probability theory the study of measure spaces with total measure one, but that would be like calling number theory the study of strings of digits which terminate. At a practical level, the opposite is true: just as number theorists study concepts (e.g. primality) that have the same meaning in every numeral system that models the natural numbers, we shall see that probability theorists study concepts (e.g. independence) that have the same meaning in every measure space that models a family of events or random variables.

And later in 275A, Notes 0: Foundations of probability theory:

Note carefully that sample spaces (and their attendant structures) will be used to model probabilistic concepts, rather than to actually be the concepts themselves. ... As it turns out, in probability theory it is often desirable to change the sample space model (for instance, one could extend the sample space by adding in new sources of randomness, or one could couple together two systems of random variables by joining their sample space models together). Because of this, we will take some care in this foundational set of notes to distinguish probabilistic concepts (such as events and random variables) from their sample space models.


...[I]n probability one usually manipulates events and random variables without explicitly specifying any given sample space. For a student raised exclusively on concrete sample space foundations of probability, this can be a bit confusing, for instance it can give the misconception that any given random variable is somehow associated to its own unique sample space, with different random variables possibly living on different sample spaces, which often leads to nonsense when one then tries to combine those random variables together.

A random variable, properly understood, is an abstract entity which is not attached to a specific sample space; a specific function on a specific sample space can model this abstract entity, but the two aren't the same mathematical object. When only discussing one random variable at a time this point can be ignored to some extent, but you really can't ignore it when discussing $n$ samples like this.
Now we can address your questions:

In the first paragraph, it is stated that $X_1$, $X_2$, ..., $X_n$ have the same distribution as $X$. This got me thinking: Do $X_1$, $X_2$, ..., $X_n$ have the same domain as $X$? Does an individual $X_i$ have the same domain as some $X_j$, for $i \neq j$?

The real answer is that the "domain" of a random variable is not an invariant concept; this question is like asking for the coordinates of a vector without choosing a basis. One can model the $X_i$ on a single shared sample space but that sample space isn't unique. You will get very confused if you try to model them all as functions on the same sample space $S$ that $X$ was originally defined on, as you tried; there simply isn't enough "room." For example if $S = \{ H, T \}$ is the sample space of a coin flip and $X$ counts the number of heads, there already isn't enough room for a second independent copy of $X$.

If $X: S \to \mathbb{R}$, what are the domains of $X_1$, $X_2$, ..., $X_n$?

$X_1, \dots X_n$ can be modeled on the sample space $S^n$, equipped with the product measure. Sticking to the coin flip example, if $S = \{ H, T \}$ is the sample space of a coin flip then $S^n = \{ H, T \}^n$ is the sample space of $n$ coin flips, and $X_i$ defined in terms of whether the $i^{th}$ flip is heads or tails constitutes $n$ iid samples from the Bernoulli distribution $\text{Ber} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)$. Since I just said "distribution" here I'm going to address your first question:

There seems to be some disagreement between the first paragraph and the definition that follows it. In the first paragraph, the sample is said to be drawn on X. But in the definition, the sample is drawn from the common distribution. Because X is a random variable and not a distribution, these two statements are not exactly the same.

This is related to the question of when two random variables are the same, which I can now offer an answer to: two random variables are the same when they have the same distribution. That's it. That's the invariant content of a random variable, the part that doesn't depend on a sample space model of it. When I say "the Bernoulli distribution $\text{Ber} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)$" I am referring to, so to speak, an isomorphism class of random variables, namely all random variables on all sample spaces with this distribution.
The subtlety here is that it does not follow that two collections of random variables $(X_1, \dots X_n), (Y_1, \dots Y_n)$ are the same if the distribution of $X_i$ is the same as the distribution of $Y_i$ for all $i$. Rather, the correct notion of sameness here is now that the joint distributions are the same. So when I say "$n$ iid samples from the Bernoulli distribution $\text{Ber} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)$" I am describing an isomorphism class of $n$-tuples of random variables (equivalently, $\mathbb{R}^n$-valued random variables), namely all $n$-tuples of random variables on all sample spaces with this joint distribution.

I am using the term "isomorphism" slightly loosely here but one can literally write down a category of random variables and in particular discuss, say, the automorphism group of a random variable (which corresponds to symmetries of its distribution) and so forth, using the concept of an algebra of random variables equipped with an expectation, as discussed e.g. here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/245a-notes-5-free-probability/

I have admired your work on SE since at least 2017, when I saw your answers about splitting fields and category theory :) So I am honored by your response. Your answer is very helpful. I had a rather rigid view of understanding when two RVs could be considered the same. (In my defense, several intermediate-level textbooks are fairly firm about RVs being functions, and given my interest in set theory, it seamed hard to imagine two functions being equal if their domains are not the same!) But your post expanded my thinking greatly.

Suppose that, for whatever reason, I still wanted to think about RVs as functions and not as abstract entities. Could I proceed as follows? Let $\mathcal{A}$ = {X | X is a random variable}. Then define an equivalence relation ~ on $\mathcal{A}$ by $X$ ~ $Y$ iff $X$ and $Y$ have the same CDF. Then the set of equivalence classes $\mathcal{A}/$~ partitions $\mathcal{A}$, and we can say two RVs are the "same" or are "equal" if they belong to the same equivalence class. Would this be a valid (albeit overly formal) way of proceeding?

@Sam: you're welcome! Yes, you can say that "has the same distribution" defines an equivalence relation on random variables, which is usually denoted $\sim$. So for example the notation $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$ means that $X$ has the normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. But this notation already implicitly involves thinking the way I've described above: after all, what is the RHS $N(\mu, \sigma)$? It's not a specific function on a specific sample space, but rather the "abstract normal distribution"!

I think I am starting to understand! The RHS $N(\mu, \sigma)$ is a "name"  for the the equivalence class containing all RVs that are normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. If $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$, then we could also name this equivalence class as "the equivalence class containing $X$". So there are many names for this equivalence class, but probably the most descriptive is $N(\mu, \sigma)$. Would you agree with this approach?
Thank you for putting up with my questions, even though many people probably find these questions to be too concerned with the formalities

@Sam: yes, that's right (or that's how I think about these things anyway). I think these types of questions are quite important so I'm happy to answer them in detail, and this specific issue of what a random variable "really is" is often poorly explained, I think. It's sort of a historical accident that we don't do probability theory the same abstract way we do group theory or manifold theory; you can do it on, say, an "abstract $\sigma$-algebra," not attached to a specific set. This lets you do things like quotient by the null sets which you can't do in the usual setup.

To answer your question I would start by defining a statistical model, for this let $\mathcal{X}$ be non-empty a set, and $\mathcal{B}$ a $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathcal{X}$. So you have a measureable space $( \mathcal{X},\mathcal{B})$, now we want to think of $$M(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{B})=\{P:\mathcal{X}\longrightarrow [0,1]: P \ \textrm{is a probability measure on}\ \mathcal{X}\}$$
Then we want to specify on a set of interest $\mathcal{P}=\{P_\theta : \theta \in \Theta\}\subset M(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{B}) $, where $\Theta$ is set, such that $|\mathcal{P}|>1$. This set $\Theta$ is of great interest, as in point estimating statistics, we want to give an educated guess about $\theta \in \Theta$, based on our random sample.
The resulting triplet $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{B},\mathcal{P})$ is defined as a statistic model.
What comes now is one way to answer to your question:
We can assume without loss of generality [take the identity map and $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},\mathbb{P}_{\theta})=(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{B},\mathcal{P})$] that there exists a family of probability spaces $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathcal{Q})=\{(\Omega, \mathcal{A},\mathbb{P}_{\theta}):\theta \in \Theta\}, \ \mathcal{Q}=\{\mathbb{P}_{\theta}:\theta \in \Theta\} \subset M(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$, such that
$$X:(\Omega, \mathcal{A}) \longrightarrow  ( \mathcal{X},\mathcal{B})$$
is a random variable, i.e. measureable map and $X$ has distribution $\mathbb{P}_{\theta}^X=P_{\theta} $, which is meant as $\mathbb{P}_{\theta}^X(B)=\mathbb{P}_{\theta}(X \in B), \ B \in \mathcal{B}$ .
Then $\mathcal{X}$ is the random sample and is induced by the r.v. $X: \Omega \longrightarrow \mathcal{X}$.
So now take $X_1, \dots , X_n \stackrel{iid}\sim P_{\theta}\in \mathcal{P}$, where $X_i: \Omega \longrightarrow \mathcal{X}, \ i=1, \dots ,n$ and $\mathcal{X}^n$ is the random sample of size $n$. Here a canonical new statistical model would be $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{B},\mathcal{P})^{\otimes n}=(\mathcal{X}^n,\mathcal{B}^{\otimes n}, \mathcal{P}_n)$, where $\mathcal{B}^{\otimes n}$ is the corresponding product $\sigma$-algebra and $\mathcal{P}_n=\{P_{\theta}^{\otimes n}: \theta \in \Theta\}\subset M(\mathcal{X}^n,\mathcal{B}^{\otimes n})$, where $P_{\theta}^{\otimes n}$ is the product measure. Which would model the independet repition of a expiremnt, which yields the random sample.
